# Are there good options to remove or disable a default Spring bean?

Tags: java, spring

The scenario that inspired this question is the `WebExceptionHandler` for Spring WebFlux:

```
@Bean
@Order(-2)
public WebExceptionHandler exceptionHandler() {
    return (exchange, ex) -> {
        // Handle exceptions
    };
}
```

In the above code example, I'm using the `@Order` annotation to ensure my exception handler is prioritized above the `DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler` Spring WebFlux ships with. This is an effective solution. So is `@Primary`. However, I really don't like either of them.

The reason behind this is it feels unpleasant to me to rely on what is order-based functionality to ensure my code behaves. I would much rather find a way to exclude `DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler` from the Spring container, so that my implementation is the only `WebExceptionHandler` available. However, `DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler` is autowired automatically by Spring, and I'm not aware of any way to exclude it.

I'm wondering what options there may be to achieve this goal.

Comment: Like it or not, your techniques are the way to override spring boot default beans.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot provides defaults with the capability to exclude, or use a user provide bean. It's one of the key capabilities.

Given the WebFlux ErrorExceptionHandler currently looks like this,

```
@AutoConfiguration(before = WebFluxAutoConfiguration.class)
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = ConditionalOnWebApplication.Type.REACTIVE)
@ConditionalOnClass(WebFluxConfigurer.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ ServerProperties.class, WebProperties.class })
public class ErrorWebFluxAutoConfiguration {

    private final ServerProperties serverProperties;

    public ErrorWebFluxAutoConfiguration(ServerProperties serverProperties) {
        this.serverProperties = serverProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(value = ErrorWebExceptionHandler.class, search = SearchStrategy.CURRENT)
    @Order(-1)
    public ErrorWebExceptionHandler errorWebExceptionHandler(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes,
            WebProperties webProperties, ObjectProvider<ViewResolver> viewResolvers,
            ServerCodecConfigurer serverCodecConfigurer, ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler exceptionHandler = new DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler(errorAttributes,
                webProperties.getResources(), this.serverProperties.getError(), applicationContext);
        exceptionHandler.setViewResolvers(viewResolvers.orderedStream().toList());
        exceptionHandler.setMessageWriters(serverCodecConfigurer.getWriters());
        exceptionHandler.setMessageReaders(serverCodecConfigurer.getReaders());
        return exceptionHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(value = ErrorAttributes.class, search = SearchStrategy.CURRENT)
    public DefaultErrorAttributes errorAttributes() {
        return new DefaultErrorAttributes();
    }

}
```

You can either,

1. Create a Bean that implements `ErrorWebExceptionHandler` rather `WebExceptionHandler`
2. Exclude `ErrorWebFluxAutoConfiguration.class` which can be done in a few ways, but normally these days via `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { ErrorWebFluxAutoConfiguration.class })`

Comment: Thank you for this. I wish there was an easier way that didn't involve hunting down the specific auto config class to know this, but thank you for the info